# dplyr - summarise_all(median) never ends, without error. Saving and reloading the dataframe solves the problem. Why?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a script that combines some data from different .csv files and then filters and summarises the data.
When I source the script, it will keep running indefinitely, without throwing an error.

I have narrowed the problem down to the summarise_all(median). If I use mean instead of median, it works fine. And if I comment out the summarise_all line, it also works fine.

I was under the impression my RStudio (or my computer) caused this problem, because when I saved the workspace with object df in it, sent it to a colleague, and she ran the # Finalize part on the loaded workspace, she had no problems.
But now I discovered that if I load that saved workspace myself, and run the # Finalize part, it also works fine.
The same goes for just saving and reloading the dataframe only (without the rest of the workspace)

So I tested a workaround where the script saves and then loads the dataframe, and this solves my problem. But it seems really strange practice to me to do this..

My data has ~37000 rows. If I perform the script on 1000 rows instead, it works **without** the workaround. So in theory, the code is correct.
But if I run it on all 37000 rows, even waiting for 4 hours does not generate a result.
If I do use the workaround, I can run all 37000 rows in ~2 minutes.

Can anybody please tell me what could cause this? I have been asking colleagues and searching online for days now and I just can't figure it out.

```
# Initiate----------------------------------------------------------------
library(tidyverse)
info <- read_tsv("./Probe Annotation.txt")

# Read data---------------------------------------------------------------

d1 <- read_tsv("./Summary.txt") %>% 
  select(-ProbeName, -ControlType)
d1_dict <- read_tsv("./DataPrint Run Summary.txt", skip=10)

d1_colnames <- colnames(d1)
d1_prep <-
  d1 %>% 
  rename_at(all_of(d1_colnames), ~ d1_dict$CaseNo)

# Gather ------------------------------------------------------------------

df <- bind_cols(info, d1_prep)
df <- df[1:1000,]

# Workaround--------------------------------------------------------------
# save(df,file="df.RData")
# load("df.RData")

# Finalize ----------------------------------------------------------------

df_final <-
  df %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Sequence)) %>%
  select(-ProbeName, -GeneName, -SystematicName) %>%
  group_by(Sequence)%>%
  summarise_all(median)
```

I tried using (stats::median) instead of (median) based on an answer here, no difference.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243083/discussion-on-question-by-elefy76-dplyr-summarise-allmedian-never-ends-with).

Answer (score 0):

Add: `setDT(df)` before `df_final <-`